# WTF BooleanField set custom value

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have the following:

forms.py:

```
student_account = BooleanField('student_account')
```

index.html

```
{{ form.student_account.label() }} {{ form.student_account(class="form-control") }}
```

And this code results into the following html:

```
<input id="student_account" name="student_account" type="checkbox" value="y">
```

How can I set the value to be 1 instead of 'y'? Why in fact all of the sudden, there is a 'y' as a value?

Comment: Nope, I am not setting it anywhere ;)

Comment: I edited my question - added more clarifying code. I use form from wtform in index.html and this results in the value set to 'y'

Comment: Sidenote: this new edit was really critical to clarifying the question better. as a general tip, a [mcve] helps best. But still, step in the right direction.

Comment: If you could go a step further and actually produce a [mcve], it would really help. Please show how index.html looks, as well as the minimal python code for creating this setup. Also, why do you "need" the value to be 1? What's the issue with it being set to "y" ?

Comment: The value ``"y"`` is [the default value of BooleanField](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/9f66d7ed26c2d79f2907edf54f67ce1d1049e07c/src/wtforms/fields/core.py#L828). Why do you expect the value to be ``1``? Did you try setting the ``default``, e.g. ``default="1"``?

Answer (score 2):

'y' is the default value for Boolean inputs' `value` attribute in wtforms.

According to the docstring for the base [Input](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/ea76ecfee562d8895e51c3bd12b0a8c5b18437bc/src/wtforms/widgets/core.py#L139) widget

> By default, the `_value()` method will be called upon the associated field
>       to provide the `value=` HTML attribute.

And `BooleanField`'s [_value method](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/ea76ecfee562d8895e51c3bd12b0a8c5b18437bc/src/wtforms/fields/core.py#L828) is

```
def _value(self):
    if self.raw_data:
        return text_type(self.raw_data[0])
    else:
        return "y"
```

If you really want a different value you could override it by setting it in the field's `render_kw` argument:

```
foo = BooleanField('bar', render_kw={'value': '1'})
```

or by subclassing `BooleanField` and overriding its `_value` method.

Usually there isn't much benefit in overriding this value; wtforms will automatically cast the value to a boolean when `form.data` is constructed.

```
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField
from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict

class MyForm(Form):
    b = BooleanField('MyBool')

f = MyForm(formdata=MultiDict({'b': 'y'})
f.data
{'b': True}

f = MyForm(formdata=MultiDict({})
f.data
{'b': False}
```